# Authorization header empty in basic jquery ajax request against a .Net Core 2.0 web api

Tags: jquery, basic-authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

PostMan, Asp.Net client, fiddler, and other HTTP clients work fine.  When I make a request with code similar to below, I get a 401.  As I debug on the web api side there is not HeaderAuthorization value.  There is a value in  the HeaderAccessControlRequestHeaders of "authorization".  I would expect to see the actual base64 encoded value coming in.

```
eid=2 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44322
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:50891
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
**Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization**
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

---

```
function getChiefComplaints() {

        //jQuery.support.cors = true;
       var symptoms = $('#txtChiefComplaints').val()
        // symptoms = symptoms.replace(",", "");

        symptoms = symptoms.replace(" ", "+");
       $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:44322/method',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',

            headers: { "Authorization": " Basic topsecretcredentials" },
            success: function (data) {
                WriteResponse(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('no data');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting authorization header directly you should set this in beforeSend object like this

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); },
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.  I have tried, at least, a version of this with no success.

Comment: $.ajax({ url: 'http://localhost:44322/service3',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password")); },...

Comment: can you please post your complete ajax call here ?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve this issue on the server side.  Using .Net Core 2.0, I had my own middleware.  I had to move the app.UserCors() statement before it and suddenly the authentication headers appeared. So all of the generic documentation stated that app.UserCors had to appear before app.UseMvc(), but I never thought to put it in front of my own custom middleware.

Thanks Chetan for your response.